# Comparing Ecore Class and Types

Tags: code-generation, xtend

I want to compare eCore-datatypes and eCore-classes in if-clauses. Something like this:

if (ent == "Entity"){}

"Entity" is the eCore-Class and "ent" an actual Object of this class.

The same question goes for eCore Datatypes.

if(ent.eType == "EBoolean"){}

How can i do that? At the moment I only compare the names with string operations.

Similiar to this:

if(ent.name.toString.equals("Entity")) {} or eType.name.toString.equals("EBoolean") but that is only a temporary solution for me.

Is there another possible more professional solution to this problems?

Comment: For classes i found out that one can use instanceof. But for types i don't know yet.

if(ent instanceof Entity){}

Answer (score 1):

Do you have generated Java classes for your EMF model? If yes, than a instanceof should work.

```
switch ent {
  Entity : {
     ...
  }
}
```

If you want to compare the EClass instances than there are constants in your generated EPackage you can use. That would be something like:

```
if (ent.eClass == MyEcorePackage::Entity) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First filter EObject for types of `class`. Further split it by `typeof(className)`.

```
for (clazz : p.EClassifiers.filter(typeof(EClass))) {
         if (clazz.name == typeof(ClassA).simpleName) { clazz.callMethodA;
  } else if (clazz.name == typeof(ClassB).simpleName) { clazz.callMethodB; }
}
```

Do the same for `EDataTypes`...